# What is the motivation behind the solution of this olympiad problem?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

> [image]

Is there a particular reason why solutions in arithmetic progression were sought for? Can you think of an alternate solution?

**Note**: This is a problem from the Indian National Mathematical Olympiad 2001.

Comment: Well...it's always a good idea to try to reduce the number of variables.  This trick takes you from three to two.  Also, the right hand simplifies in a very attractive way.  So I think it is a fairly natural thing to try...that said, I don't see any particular reason why you'd expect it to work out.  Looks to me just like a sensible line of attack.

Comment: @lulu being an Olympiad problem, the solution was probably thought of before the question

Comment: For those who might need more question sets : http://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/subjects/mathematics/previous-question-papers-and-solutions

Answer (score 6):

The righthand side suggests naming the differences. We might as well assume that $x\le y\le z$ and set $a=y-x$ and $b=z-y$. The equation then becomes

$$3y^2+a^2+b^2+2(b-a)y=ab(a+b)\;,$$

and at that point it's easy to see that setting $a=b$ would simplify matters greatly. At this point it could still turn out, of course, that the simplification is useless, because the additional requirement kills off too many solutions, but it's so much easier to work with that it should definitely be investigated, and it turns out to be fruitful.